# Android Layout Background color change causes runtime exception

Tags: android, runtimeexception

When I'm trying to change a color of the background:

```
RelativeLayout rl;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondo);
    rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.secondo);
    rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(250, 250, 32, 32));
}
```

I'm getting a nasty `RuntimeException`. Do You know, why is this happening?

LogCat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: (...) 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 3):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo:
>   (...)  java.lang.NullPointerException

The `NullPointerException` is because `rl` is null

This

```
 rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.secondo);
```

should be

```
 rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl);
 // reference the id that you mentioned in secondo.xml
```

> But it's not there

So you don't have id for RelativeLayout

Add the id to relative layout in `secondo.xml`

```
 <RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/rl"
```

Comment: @user3212350 then how you can find the view. add a id to relative layout in xml

Comment: Someone is downvoting my posts on purpose

Comment: then flag it to moderator,if someone is downvoting your posts on purpose.

Comment: @Stephen user downvoted on only 2 posts serially. Those 2 posts were recently answered. so he browsed and downvoted. If it was a case of dwonvoting more than few times i would have flagged But i will wait and see if this behaviour continues before flagging. I accept any downvote with a  reason coz it helps me correct my mistake and also helps the community by large.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your main xml name in `setContentView(R.layout.secondo);` and relativeLayout name in `rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.secondo);`

`secondo` is same and should be different.

Answer (score 0):

Ooh , you should catch the id of layout not layout >>
:: RelativeLayout rl = findViewById(R.id.yourid);
that you put for the layout

I think it will be done :)